# Unable to handle unhandled exceptions in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to handle any unhandled exception in my Xamarin Forms Android app. I read that I can catch them in event handlers added in OnCreate in the MainActivity like so:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ...
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomain_UnhandledException;
}

static void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I cause an exception from my MainPage:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Exception_Btn.Clicked += (object s, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        int var1 = 1;
        int var2 = 0;
        // Cause a DivideByZeroException
        var1 /= var2;
    };
}
```

However, the event handler is never triggered, app breaks and Debug window says the exception is still unhandled. What am I missing?

Comment: What you're doing is catching global exceptions. However, this doesn't work the same way as `try...catch` where the code carries on as normal. The exception will still trigger, but the `UnhandledException` event will simply catch it before the app is forced to shutdown.

Comment: @Tom But shouldn't my debug message print before the app is forced to shutdown? It doesn't.

Comment: I found out that it does reach the code after the exception goes unhandled twice, if I keep the app alive in Visual Studio and continue past the unhandled exceptions. So my problem is rather that the app is forced to shutdown before I am able to log the exception.

Comment: Actually, the debug message is printed before the app is forced to shut down. As I cannot add the picture in the comment, I posted an answer with a capture.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the debug message is printed before the app is forced to shut down.

If you add a breakpoint at the end of `CurrentDomain_UnhandledException` function(In the capture below, the breakpoint is on line30)you will see that.

[image]